# Counting function in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I have a list that I am going through using list comprehension.
Each time I get a a value from the list, I want to output where I currently am in the list.

So if a list has 5 items, the output would be something like this (Including my code for the list comp):

```
values = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
modded_values = [print(val.upper()) for val in values]
```

So the output from print would be:

```
(1/5)A
(2/5)B
(3/5)C
...
```

I made a small function (which doesn't work), as the variable value starts from 0 each time the function is called.

```
def counter(l):
    list_length = len(l)
    current = +1
    return '(' + str(current) + '/' + str(list_length) + ')'
```

Which would be used like this:

```
values = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
modded_values = [print(counter(values)+val.upper()) for val in values]
```

Comment: Why are you using a list comprehension to call the `print()` function? You'll get lists with `None` objects, almost certainly useless for any other code.

Comment: Use the `enumerate()` function to add a counter to a `for` loop. If you are not producing a list (you appear to be producing *output to `stdout`* instead), then use a normal `for` loop, not a list comprehension.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Could you give me an example? I am not really using print, I am using a custom function which takes an input value prints it, and also returns the value, that way I can use the values returned and output to stdout at the same time.

Comment: Why do that at all? Why not just use the list after it is built to print results? `print(*list, sep='\n')` would print a list object with each element on a separate line. I've duplicated you  to the canonical 'how to count in a loop' question.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It's not the same though. My code takes a long time to run as it makes requests to a webserver. For security reasons I am not able to post the real code, so I dumbed it down, but the priciple is the same. Because it takes to long, I would like to see how far down the list the code is, instead of waiting blindly for it to finish having no idea where it currently is in the looop

Comment: Is it that hard to adapt the examples in that question to your situation? All you are doing is add one more target in the `for` loop, and the `enumerate()` function.